# How to process CSV with different columns in CDAP (Datafusion)?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have a case where I receive multiple CSV from third parties (little hard to make them change the format), and those CSVs should have the same columns, but sometimes one or more columns are missing. If I use CDAP File (reading as text) followed by a Wrangler to process the CSV the Wrangler with the following directive:

```
parse-as-csv :body '\\t' true
cleanse-column-names
```

It will assume that all files read have the same column format and will mess the data of the files that have less or more column than the first file.

So far I tried to use the File to read as blob and to have the output as bytes with a Wrangler configured with this directive:

```
set-type :body string
parse-as-csv :body '\t' true
cleanse-column-names
```

But now I do not even have any output (or error), so I am clueless how to parse those non uniform files. Is CDAP able to handle this case? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the directive [set-column](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/current/en/user-guide/data-preparation/directives/set-column.html) to add new columns to the files which don't have all the needed columns. By and large, I would recommend you to look into all the [directives documentation](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/en/user-guide/data-preparation/directives/index.html) to preprocess your files.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is when the columns does not align, for example one file I have the columns A|B|C|D and the second file the columns are only A|C|D, how can I handle this case?

Comment: In that case, I would use Python pandas to preprocess the data; I think there is no directive that directly does what you are asking for.

Comment: if it’s always column B missing then you can use set-column :B exp:{ ... }